# Codename One - Crash due to TextFields

Tags: codenameone

I had my app working just fine a few days ago and then I noticed the first problem. I had to tap twice in order to make a button go to the next screen. Also happened to the checkBoxes. Had to tap twice to make them change.

But now it got serious. Since yesterday when I tap on a TextField the app **freezes and then crashes**.
The only significant changes I remember I did were 2: I uploaded an image for the App Icon and I edited the TitleArea UIID. I removed the TOP and BOTTOM margins. It also affected some of my label and button UIID, because now they don't show on the device

When I run the simulator, the doble tap also occurs, but the TextFields work fine and the Button and Label UIID look the way they should.

Any ideas why this happens?

I am right now working with old versions to try to determine the reason, but no luck so far. Thanks

Comment: On which OS? What are you doing in terms of the text field/text area? Did you enable crash protection? If this is on Android did you connect a cable and look at DDMS output?

Comment: I am using Android. After I fill in the TextFields I move their getText() to a hashtable and then I store that hashtable using the Storage class, but the app is crashing after I tap on any of them. It won't even show the keyboard. Buttons and Pickers are working fine. No crash protection now. I will do it. Also no cable. Last night I copied old code into the StateMachine file and it still crashed, so I am assuming the problem is in the builder. To prove it I am building all again using the same StateMachine code. I will post any updates

Comment: Ok, something really strange happened. I created a whole new project and on my first screen I edited some labels with colored fonts and backgrounds, and NONE of the backgrounds are shown on my device. They only show on the simulator. I will save my data and re install Netbeans

Comment: Are you using gradients? I suggest avoiding gradients.

Comment: I am selecting the gradient so I can select the colors, but I use the same color from both color pickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a solid color rather than a gradient with the same colors. Gradients are slow and problematic across platforms so you are paying a lot for something that you aren't even using.

We'll need a better test case to reproduce crashing, I think that what you initially saw when you submitted the issue was a regression in the text input that we since resolved in the build servers.